# vs code not running my code, task.json error

Tags: json

[image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz1C8.png)
vs code is not running my tasks properly and keeps giving me errors in tasks.json

reinstall vscode and all the extensions, reinstall mingw
I am expecting to have a helpful answer and solution for my problem